# Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'TableView' in coercion

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm getting the error `Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'TableView'` in coercion

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let DestViewController = segue.destinationViewController  as TableView  //Error 

    DestViewController.label.text = TEXT.text  
}
```

Comment: If my answer answers your question, then could you please accept it with the check mark? If it is missing something, then please, tell me in the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.destinationViewController` returns a UIViewController, not a UIView.

This error is being thrown because you are essentially trying to downcast a UIViewController to a UITableView when the closest thing is a UITableView*Controller*. The latter is a subtype of UIViewController, whereas the former is a subtype of UIView. Hence, you cannot downcast from UIViewController to UITableView, but instead to UITableViewController.

If you want `DestViewController` to be the tableView (consider renaming to something like `destTable`), you will have to say:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let destTable = (segue.destinationViewController as UITableViewController).tableView

    destTable.label.text = TEXT.text  //suggestion: change `TEXT` to just `text` or `txt`, etc.; just not all uppercase

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what i needed